# Run java App Over Network With A Single JRE

Tags: java

I have a java app which I need to distribute across a local network of over 50 computers.
I created the app using some third party libraries and APIs that I copied directly to my classpath on my development machine.

Now I need to distribute the app as well as the JRE with the custom APIs over the network. Having to copy and paste the app in all the systems is a really huge work, talk more about having to install the JRE and then copying all the third party APIs to the ext directory.

Is there any way of installing one JRE on a server system and then other systems can run the java app using that same JRE. If not, what is the best and effective way to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JRE is the OS process (`java.exe`) that runs your Java code, so the JRE has to run on each server. However, you don't have to *install* the JRE. You can run the JRE from a network share. Same for your Jar files.

See this message thread: [Running Java from a shared folder](https://www.java.net/node/658720)

Comment: This is something I've tried already. But the client system doesn't seem to be finding the shared folder even after adding the shared folder path to the environmental variable of the client system.

Comment: @Charles Environment variable? I'm talking about running Java straight from a share: `\\myserver\myshare\jre17\bin\java.exe -jar \\myserver\myshare\mycode\myjar.jar` --- Or map the drive: `net use m: \\myserver\myshare` then `m:\jre17\bin\java.exe -jar m:\mycode\myjar.jar`

Comment: Thanks lot @Andreas. This worked perfectly and saved me a whole lot of time and stress. This would be the perfect deployment strategy with a few tweaks from my end. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you have the best design approach here.

The idea of a central JRE with all libraries coppied into a central location is not how java should work. I would not do it. Just install a JRE it on each machine, thats the point of java - write once and use on each machine.

As for your LIB dependencies, If you use eclipse you can just export a runnable jar file which could embed the libs into your jar file (check your liciences of each lib to make sure this is allowed). This would copy all the libs into your jar file so it can be launched on each machine without any configuration.

The other option is that you can just add a class path command when launching your jar file (that contains relative directory)

```
java -cp 'MyProgram.jar:libs/*' main.Main
```

If installing this on each machine is not an option have a look at [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net). This can package a JRE with your application.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've tried lauch4j. It makes the size of the very large cos of the bundled jre. so that isn't an option.